# How can a Bokeh figure's rendered HTML be exported directly to a string?

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm generating Bokeh figures and passing them via an HTMLResponse to a webpage under Django. To get the figures' HTML as a monolithic string, my current solution is as follows:

```
from os import remove
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, save

def render_chart_to_string():
    chart_figure = figure(
        # parameters
    )

    chart_path = str(datetime.now().timestamp()).replace('.', '') + '.html'
    output_file(chart_path, mode='inline')
    save(chart_figure)

    with open(chart_path, 'r') as chart_file:
        chart_string = chart_file.read()

    remove(chart_path)

    return chart_string
```

How can I pass the HTML directly to a string, instead of creating a needless file? I've tried using StringIO, but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the [`file_html`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html#html-files) function to get the HTML as a string.

```
from bokeh.resources import CDN

html = file_html(plot, CDN)
```

Comment: Thank you! The only other change I had to make using this method was manually including the Bokeh JS scripts in my template. (the string I got from output_file(figure, mode='inline') had all the relevant functions included)